# Does the Kachurovskii's theorem characterize monotone operators?

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm interested in the [Kachurovskii's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kachurovskii%27s_theorem) in the Euclidean case: Let $m \ge 1$ be an integer and let $g: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function that is an *increasing monotone operator*, i.e.,

$$(g(x) - g(y))^\top (x-y)  \ge 0$$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

**Question**. Is $g$ necessarily the derivative of some convex $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$? In other words, does Kachurovskii's theorem characterizes all increasing monotone operators?